# Why i can see login form if im already login

Tags: php

Hi guys can i ask what is the problem on my code.

all i want is if there is someone already login then if i click back i don`t want to see the login form what is the problem in my code thank you for you help

//php for check if i login

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

<?php

    if (!isset($_SESSION["member_id"])) {
        header("Location:index.php");
    }

?>
```

//html

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once("check_login.php");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>


    <head>
        <title>All Members</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script>
            function confirmDelete() {
                if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this member?")) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>

        <?php require_once("top_nav.php"); ?>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>All Members</h1>

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
                <?php
                    require_once("db_open.php");
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM members";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);
                    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $delete_link = "delete_member_db.php?member_id=".$row["member_id"];
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$row["member_id"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row["member_email"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row["member_full_name"]."</td>";
                            echo "<td><a href='".$delete_link."' onClick='return confirmDelete();' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Delete</a></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<p>No members to show...</p>";
                    }
                    require_once("db_close.php");
                ?>
            </table>

        </div>

    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: your question would better fit to this stackexchange site imho: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: delete your link tag in the check login file and any white space

Comment: i still see it  i can go to login form i want that if there account is already login i cant see the login form if im clicking the back button

Comment: Pretty sure in this context `session_start()` is creating a _new_ session when you press back, therefore no session variables will have been set and you will always see the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies, I didn't get your question exactly but as per my understanding, in order to avoid login page view if user is logged in, you have to check with another condition on login page that,

```
if (isset($_SESSION["member_id"])) {
   header("Location:some_page_name.php");
}
```

I think, You have checked condition

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["member_id"])) {
    header("Location:index.php");
 }
```

which is useful for pages visible after logging in...